google client api: как правильно создать экземпляр класса RenderAccountIssuesRequestPayload?
Для связи по API с Google Merchat Center я использую две библиотеки.



клиентскую библиотеку php 7.4




библиотеку примеров googleads-shopping-samples



Но когда пытаюсь вызвать примерно вот такую функцию
    public function get_info($accountId) {

    $payload1 = new RenderAccountIssuesRequestPayload();
    $var1 = $payload1->setContentOption('CONTENT_OPTION_UNSPECIFIED');

    $status = $this->session->service->merchantsupport->renderaccountissues(
            $this->session->merchantId, $var1);

    return $status;

}

То оно вызывает ошибку, о том, что параметр $var1 = NULL, а должен он быть

must be an instance of
Google\Service\ShoppingContent\RenderAccountIssuesRequestPayload, null
given, called in /home/AccountstatusesSample.php on line 74

Вот документация по функции renderaccountissues(), которую я вызываю.
Пытаюсь сделать, как тут написано
Не пойму, как правильно задать этот экземпляр класса RenderAccountIssuesRequestPayload?
Может быть, кто-то сталкивался с похожей проблемой?
Вот полный текст ошибки.

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
Google\Service\ShoppingContent\Resource\Merchantsupport::renderaccountissues()
must be an instance of
Google\Service\ShoppingContent\RenderAccountIssuesRequestPayload, null
given, called in
/home/tatam0/tadam/test/php_merchant_api/AccountstatusesSample.php on
line 74 and defined in
/home/tatam0/tadam/test/php_merchant_api/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/ShoppingContent/Resource/Merchantsupport.php:54

Вот привожу ссылку на файлы Merchantsupport.php, AccountstatusesSample.php, которые упоминаются в этой ошибке, чтобы можно было видеть наглядно рабочий код. А также ссылка на сам класс RenderAccountIssuesRequestPayload, который я нашел в файлах клиентской библиотеки, упоминаемой в п. 1) - см. выше

Ну как минимум вот это $payload1->setContentOption('CONTENT_OPTION_UNSPECIFIED'); сэттер, он ничего не возвращает, а вторым параметром сюда renderaccountissues() ожидается экземпляр класса RenderAccountIssuesRequestPayload, попробуйте передать туда $payload1.

@Simon спасибо за совет. Действительно так, как вы порекомендовали сработало. Но теперь вопрос возник следующий: а как мне передать в этом экземпляре класса нужное мне зачение вот это, о котором говорится в официальной документации по этой функции renderaccountissues().

Вы же уже устанавливаете его при помощи сэттера $payload1->setContentOption('CONTENT_OPTION_UNSPECIFIED');

@Simon К сожалению, этот метод почему-то не срабатывает. Я пробовал и как строку передавать $payload1->setContentOption("PRE_RENDERED_HTML"); и как константу вот так $payload1->setContentOption(PRE_RENDERED_HTML);, но ответ от сервера приходит в том же формате, который установлен по умолчанию (а не в PRE_RENDERED_HTML, как я ожидал).
